# How can I show that this two things are equal without solving the definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have been trying to prove that this integral is equal to that sum. However I have to do that without solving the integral itself which makes it harder.I have tried proving it using the mean value theorem of Calculus but I can only seem to prove that that sum is the image of a given c which is between 0 and 1. However, I can't seem to prove that that's the exact c whose image is the integral. I am not even sure if that's the way to go.

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{2-x²}dx= \frac \pi 4 + \frac 1 2$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT If you let $y=\sqrt{2-x²}$ can you see how your equation is connected with a circle's area?

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(x) = \sqrt{2-x^2}$ which is the graph of the upper semi-circle. So, $\int_0^1 \sqrt{2-x^2} \, dx$ is the area under the graph of $f$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$.

But if you draw a picture, you'll realise that this area is the sum of the area of a sector and a right-triangle. I leave it to you to figure out the various dimensions of these figures to compute the area.

---

This very simple idea can be easily generalized to imply that for all $x \in [-r, r]$
\begin{align}
\int_0^x \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \, dt &= \dfrac{1}{2} r^2 \arcsin\left( \dfrac{x}{r}\right) + \dfrac{1}{2} x \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}
\end{align}
This can be done without calculating any antiderivatives. The first term is the (signed) area of a sector, and the second term is the (signed) area of a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

$y=\sqrt{2-x^2} \implies x^2+y^2 =2$, which is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ (just the top half) centered at the origin. If the integral had been to $\sqrt{2}$, this problem would have been solved already because that gives us the area of the quarter circle, $\frac{2\pi}{4}$ = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

But this integral stops part way, leaving a little sliver whose area is generally hard to find. So what to do?

Well we get lucky. Notice that $(1,1)$ is a point on the circle. Drawing vertical and horizontal lines from that point to the axes shows that the area of the circle equals the area of two slivers and a square of side length $1$. Because of the symmetry across the line $y=x$, the two slivers have the same area giving that

$$2A + 1 = \frac{\pi}{2} \implies A = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2}$$

The final area of the integral is

$$\frac{\pi}{2} - A = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Compute the areas directly under circular arc radius $\sqrt2.$ The sector is recognized to be one-eighth of full circle area and the other an isosceles right triangle:

$$  \frac{\pi \sqrt2 ^2}{8} +\dfrac{1\cdot 1}{2}= \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac12.$$

[image]